# solve $y(x)=\cos \left(y'(x)\right) + y'(x)\sin (y'(x)), y(0)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

solve $$y(x)=\cos (y'(x)) + y'(x)\sin (y'(x)), y(0)=1$$

with wolfram alpha I got that a solution is $y(x)=x\arcsin x+\cos (\arcsin x)$

but I have no idea how to find it.

I tried transforming into an exact equation by letting $u=y'$ then I get $y=\frac{u^2}{2}$

I just realised this is wrong (because $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{u^2}{2}=u'u\neq y'$) so there's no point posting the rest of my work.

any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Apply the chain rule of calculus.

Comment: I got $\cos (y'(x))y''(x)=1$ am I on the right track? now what?

Comment: Yes and you also have the case where $y'(x) = 0 \Rightarrow y(x)=y(0)=1$. Now what can you say about this form you get ? **HINT:** $u'cos(u)=?$

Comment: @Dolma thank you. I got $y'(x)=\arcsin x$. I don't really know how to integrate $\arcsin$, but suppose I do. Wolfram alpha gives this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+arcsin+%28x%2Bc%29+dx which doesn't look like the other solution I have which I stated in the question. what's going on here?

Comment: @Dolma I just realised it is the same thing. thank you very much